# Why Math.max(NaN, <any_number>) returns NaN?

Tags: javascript

Why comparing NaN to any number in Math.max() returns NaN??

For example `Math.max(NaN,5,3,7)` returns NaN.

Also `Math.max(Infinity, NaN, 5,3)` return NaN too.

NaN is a **falsy** value.

But `Math.max(false,4,5)` does returns the largest i.e. 5.

I was getting some numbers from an API every second and compared the current fetched number with the previous one. But in some fetch it got `NaN` and after that the result was constantly `NaN`.

So what's the reason for this?

Comment: Because that's how the method is defined in the spec. If  any parameter cannot be converted into a number that is not `NaN`, the return value is `NaN`.

Comment: and, `false` coerces to `0` when needed, but `NaN` is ... not a number.

Comment: Read the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-math.max).

Comment: It makes sense if you think of `NaN` as “mathematically undefined or unusable result” like `Math.atanh(2)` or `Math.log(-1)`. This has absolutely nothing to do with “falsy”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.max tries to convert passed values to numbers. If it cannot do that, it returns NaN.

`+true` is `1`

`+false` is `0`

`Math.max(true, 0`) returns `1`

`Math.max(Infinity, 1)` returns `Infinity`

`Math.max(NaN,5,3,7)` returns `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `Math.max` expect all the parameter to be a valid number.

As the documentation metioned:

**If at least one of arguments cannot be converted to a number, the result is NaN.**

The `NaN` is not considered a valid number, so the `Math.max` will output `NaN`